# The reply button being full width makes it hard to scroll the blog comments

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, blog, mobile-chrome

I'm reading the blog on my phone ([example article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/20/pandemic-changed-traffic-trends-stack-exchange-sites/)), and scrolling through the comments, when I tap on the highlighted area to scroll. I expect that dragging there will scroll the page, but it doesn't. Instead it pops up the reply to comment form. This makes it quite hard to scroll because you need to be careful that you don't tap any of the reply bars.

The comment form should only be shown if you actually tap on "Reply". Tapping and dragging to the right of it should be no different to tapping anywhere else.

[image: screenshot of blog comments]

Comment: To be honest, I prefer it like this. I dislike small buttons, and waste way too much time trying to tap them. Also, the row has its own background color, indicating it's all one big button.

Comment: As a side note, mobile web refers to the actual Q&A sites only, the blog has a different mechanism behind the scenes, so that tag isn't relevant for the blog.

Comment: I think it's a relevant tag, unless there's a better one for the mobile blog theme?

Comment: Ideally, a [tag:mobile-device], but not sure if it's a good idea to create such tag now. There are separate tags for each mobile browser though.

Comment: @Shadow Worth pointing out that the reply button could still be full width without preventing scrolling. For example you can touch any regular HTML link and then drag to scroll without the browser opening the link. The problem with the blog is that it immediately opens the form on the initial touch, rather than on the *release* of the touch if the user didn't scroll. So it would be possible to have the wider button if a lot of users like you appreciate it, while also fixing the scrolling problem.

Comment: Well that's true, but in that case the button width is less relevant.

Comment: By the way, I think this happens in all browsers (though it’d be less of a problem on desktop). I reproduced the problem on mobile Safari at least.

Comment: It shouldn't listen to onmousedown or onmouseup actions, but onclick. BTW, the MDN recommends to use onmousedown along with the onclick. Obviously, I disagree.